# Can Git software (e.g. Gitbox, Github, SourceTree) use a remote repo instead of local?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, gitbox

I like using Git software to push commits, but the ones I use (Gitbox, Github, SourceTree) all ask for a local repo when adding a new repo to them.

Thing is, my repo is on my development server not my local machine.

So can Git software use a remote Git repo as a development repo, then push that to your main repo (e.g. Github or Bitbucket)?

Otherwise it seems you cannot use the software and have to resort to command line over SSH.

Thanks

Comment: Are the files on your local machine for editing? How do you development if the files are not on your local machine? Can you run a Git GUI on the remote machine and tunnel it to your local machine with "ssh -X"?

Comment: I use an editor which edits files over SFTP (Coda for Mac). So I don't need, or want, my files on my local machine. I use a few machines to develop in so do t want to setup MySQL/apache/php on all of them and a repo on each for my projects, be a nightmare. So I have one development machine a access from all others. I am surprised git software can't deal with remote repos as the working version. I don't know about running git GUIs on the remote, I doubt it, I don't have x or anything like that running, it's just a centos web server.

Answer (score 6):

One solution, which doesn't rely on the front-end to support manipulating a remote repo directly, would be to mount the remote as a networked filesystem. If you only have SSH access to the remote machine, you could try using [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) via [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) (on Linux) or [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.com/) on Mac OS X. Or depending on your preferences and setup, you could use SMB, NFS, DAV, or another network filesystem.

Another way to do it, that I bring up in the comments, is to export the network filesystem from your development machine to your server. I do this so that I can mount my current working copy on multiple machines at once, and also so that I still have my local working copy even when I'm not connected to the server.

You write:

> I am surprised git software can't deal with remote repos as the working version.

Most Git GUIs do some of their work by calling out to the `git` command. In order for them to support remote operation, core Git would have to as well. It is written in a mix of C and shell script; all of that would have to be rewritten to cope with remote files.

A text editor has a much easier job; it reads one file when you open it, and writes when you save, while Git reads and writes many files in the course of a single operation like `commit`.

A networked filesystem would mean that all tools (Git and otherwise) will work on your remote files. Instead of building a layer into each and every application to support networked file access, doing it in the kernel (or via FUSE) and then just treating it like a local filesystem gives you that support in every application for free.

Comment: If git software can't deal with remote repos for my development version then this sounds like a good option, adding the remote as a network drive. Will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: @LaurenceCope I'm guessing that most Git frontends can't operate remotely, but I don't have experience with most of them. Actually, I tend to do it the opposite way around; export the development directory on my local disk to the servers that I'm testing on. I happen to use SMB for this purpose because I'm already using it for other reasons, but any network filesystem should work.

Comment: Update: it seems GitHub and Gitbox cannot "see" the .git files when the remote is mounted on a sshfs drive. I am not getting any status, or any information about the repo at all :(. I can see the .git files in Finder Ok though.

Comment: Was anyone able to actually use git that way?

Comment: "...In order for them to support remote operation, core Git would have to as well."
This is not true at all. Git could be installed on the remote machine, the software could simply ssh to it, execute whatever git commands it needs, and then update the UI locally. I'm surprised this tool does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, Git is a [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control). The fact that you don't connect to a remote server to commit stuff is *by design*.

What you want to do is have local Git repos that push code to your integration server (the one that actually runs the code). It's like deploying, only you deploy to a test server instead of production.

This is normally achieved by having a shared Git repository you push to. This repo [should be bare](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/shared-repositories-should-be-bare-repositories/). Besides the bare shared repo, you'll want a non-bare clone of the shared Git repo which will serve as your Apache docroot.

When the shared repo receives a commit, it will make the docroot repo execute `git pull`.

This can be achieved by using [post-receive hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) on the shared repo.

The docroot repo is checked out on a specific branch (let's say `develop`). So even if you commit stuff to other branches and push them, the server won't be affected.

This allows you to setup multiple deployment repositories, so you could have another branch `prod` associated with one of those that would actually update production code when you push stuff to it.

It also allows you to store incomplete / on-going work on a shared branch that doesn't deploy at all, so that you know the thing you've been working on your laptop is safe on the shared repo, even though it can't be sent to the test server because it's not complete and would break the test server, making other people unable to work or something.

[This article](http://danbarber.me/using-git-for-deployment/) goes in detail how to setup all that. I've done it before, it works well.

Comment: Problem is we use several local machines to develop on. Whether its my own Mac or laptop, or my developers PCs and laptops or home etc. We do not want to have to setup web servers on all these for local development. We all therefore access the remove DEV server to work on. It means we can develop our systems whenever and wherever and do not have to worry about the machine setup we are developing on. We only need an IDE on the local machines. We connect via SFTP and work that way. Setting up all our dev sites on every machine we use is going backwards in this cloud age in my opinion.

Comment: In the configuration I described, you don't need local servers. You'll have a shared server, but instead of editing the files in it via SFTP, you commit and push. The shared Git repo will take care of moving the files to the shared web server.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way for myself:
in Transmit (FTP client) there is an option to 'Mount favorite as disk'. SourceTree can work as expected with this 'virtual' disk.

One limitation though: you can mount the disk and start SourceTree only after you made all the changed in code and ready to make commit/push, it will not work if you keep SourceTree and ssh disk mounted while working on code. For some reason disk mounted by Transmit doesn't update files content live, but only after unmount/mount action.

Comment: I have Transmit.app on my desktop already to try it! I shall give it a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem about a year ago - unfortunately I couldn't find any consistent, reliable answer. I googled for weeks, thinking it was my search terms that weren't successful - trying every which way.

[The set up we had was each developer had their own dev server - having them separate from machines meant that sites could be developed anywhere, dev servers could be set up to be exactly the same as live environments and the sysadmin could keep them upgraded and backed up - i fully see the advantage of having a separate development server to the working machine, with one of the few downsides being no git apps!]

Everything that relies on file mounts or spoofing your computer into thinking a remote drive is local is fine for general file browsing, but Git apps tend to flake out when the connection is intermittent. Other times you have to do things in a certain way, just to see a `git status`

I know this is not the answer you want to hear as I was in your situation a while ago and know exactly how you feel, **but** the best thing you can do is *use git on the command line*.

I hate to be one of those *command line is better* Stack Overflow answerers, but in this situation I couldn't find anything that was up to scratch, to be used all day every day by multiple developers.

I was also against it at the time, I prefer the prettier, easier to use UI but since learning the command line & git, I have never looked back. When starting my own projects at home I find myself using terminal over any apps as I find many of them confusing!

It not only helps with your command line confidence, but my Git knowledge has improved tenfold since using the terminal, as the apps often hide a lot of the happenings.

Comment: I do like using git commands in the terminal, but examining log/commit/diff in console is so much better in visual tools (Git Extensions, Beyond Compare)

Answer (score 0):

7 years later, the goal is for Git to be able to use a virtual disk, through **[VFS for Git](https://vfsforgit.org/)**.

> The Virtual Filesystem for Git (formerly GVFS) is an open source system that enables Git to operate at enterprise-scale.
>   It makes using and managing massive Git repositories possible.
>
> VFS for Git virtualizes the filesystem beneath your Git repository so that Git tools see what appears to be a normal repository when, in fact, the files are not actually present on disk.
>   VFS for Git only downloads files as they are needed.

This is not (yet) part of Git itself, but:

For that, Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) will help managing such a virtual disk by introducing a **new hook "`post-index-change`"**, which will be called when the on-disk index file changes: that can help e.g. a virtualized working tree implementation.

See [commit 1956ecd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1956ecd0ab26dea9c3ed6b9afe334101d9d12f60) (15 Feb 2019) by [Ben Peart (`benpeart`)](https://github.com/benpeart).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5795a75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5795a75f9bd7a7f008b213c2f099e8c6b0468512), 25 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### `read-cache`: add `post-index-change` hook
>
> Add a `post-index-change` hook that is invoked after the index is written in
>   `do_write_locked_index()`.
>
> This hook is meant primarily for notification, and cannot affect the outcome of git commands that trigger the index write.
>
> The hook is passed a flag to indicate whether the working directory was
>   updated or not and a flag indicating if a `skip-worktree` bit could have
>   changed.
>   These flags enable the hook to optimize its response to the index change notification.